# How to create an array of name and value of multiple input fields in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wan to create an array/object of name and value pair of multiple input fields like `[{street: value1, city: value2}]`.

```
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input';

handleChange(name,value) {
    var arr = [{[name]: value}];
}
<Input type='text' name='street' defaultValue={this.props.fieldValue} 
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,"street")} />
<Input type='text' name='city' defaultValue={this.props.fieldValue} 
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,"city")} />
```

I don't want to use `react state`. I have checked this: [How to handle multiple controlled inputs with react es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358017/how-to-handle-multiple-controlled-inputs-with-react-es6) But there `state` has been used. Also followed this: [How to add multiple form input results into array State in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639108/how-to-add-multiple-form-input-results-into-array-state-in-react).

I am guessing that, it can be resolved by lodash assign or Object.assign.

Comment: Just use `this.handleChange.bind(this)`. Then use `handleChange(event)` and inside, get `event.target`; that's the `<input>`. Grab `event.target.name` and `event.target.value` for the name and current value.

Comment: @ChrisG Its updating every time. Means when I enter in `city` it returns `{city: abc}` and when I enter in `street` it returns `{street: xyz}`. While I wants it like this: `{city: abc, street: xyz}`

Comment: I see; all you need is `arr[e.target.name] = e.target.value;`

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, thanks. Resolved now.